# Grand Central Dispatch Concurrency

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, grand-central-dispatch

Here's my scenario....

I have a Core MIDI app that detects Note On and Note Off messages which is working nicely.

I have have some midiSend methods that send messages back to the controller to illuminate LEDs - also working fine.

What I want to do now is on the Note Off message have the LED blink on and off. This is my code:

```
[midiListener performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimer:) withObject:midiMsgParts waitUntilDone:YES];


-(void)startTimer:(NSDictionary *)dict {

ledIntervalCount = 0;
ledIntervalTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(ledIntervalLoop:)
                                                  userInfo:dict
                                                   repeats:YES];
}



-(void)ledIntervalLoop:(NSTimer *)inboundTimer{

NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[inboundTimer userInfo]];

NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

UInt32 onCommand = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"noteOn"] intValue];
//UInt32 offCommand = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"noteOff"] intValue];
UInt32 theNote = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"note"] intValue];

ledIntervalCount++;
if (ledIntervalCount > 3) {
    [ledIntervalTimer invalidate];
    ledIntervalTimer = nil;
} else {

    if(ledIntervalCount %2){

        [self sendNoteOnIlluminate:onCommand midiNote:theNote];

    }else{

        [self sendNoteOnCommand:onCommand midiNote:theNote];

    }

  }

}
```

So I'm using an `NSTimer` to alternate the LED on/off commands. It works fine when I press a single button but not when I press multiple ones at the same time. It seems like it only picks on the last call to the startTimer method.

This is where I think I need to implement a dispatch queue with GCD. So that each `NSTimer` will execute in full without being interrupted by the method calls that follow.

Am I correct? Will GCD allow me to have the `NSTimer` run concurrently?

GCD is a new concept to me so some guidance on how I might implement it would help. I've read through some of the reference guides but need to see some example code in the context of my scenario. I guess what I'm asking here is, what part of my code would go in the block?

Comment: you can have N times without GCD / many threads

Comment: you said that it didn't give you the desired result so I ask you to please state what you wanna do.

Comment: AH you invalidate the timers anyway... after 3 tries. ALL -- you need X counters for X timers, you have 1 counter for X timer

Comment: I've implemented a Timer class instead with an autorelease wrapping the allocation. Each time I need the timer I create a new object and pass values to properties. The object gets released when the timer invalidates.

I'd still like to understand how to creat and use dispatch queue to achieve the same results but for now my new class works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was calling the class from within a method wrapped in an autorelease. I now run this on the main thread and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

AH you invalidate the timers anyway... after 3 tries. ALL -- you need X counters for X timers, you have 1 counter for X timer

instead of one long ledIntervalCount, have a NSMutableArray with ledIntervalCounts! One per timer

then in the userInfo for the timer, provide the index to the counter that is to be used